# How can I get list of apps, images and videos of my device in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-device-info

I want to get list of apps, images and videos from my device and show them into list, how can i do this using react native?

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many modules for this like 
[react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking](https://github.com/HydromanAG/react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking)  or [react-native-installed-apps](https://github.com/dimapaloskin/react-native-installed-apps#readme) for installed apps and [react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll#readme) to access the gallery